# How can i make my loop for statement Display only the amount of even numbers entered up to 100 starting at 0? Would int.tryparse work

Tags: c#

Below is a even # loop to 100, Is it possible to not show 100 even numbers but up to 50 even numbers equaling 100? Like if I used a int.tryparse could I choose how many even numbers to display at the beginning of the app.
 the number doesn't matter I would like to know if it is possible before I move on from basic for loops

```
 {
                for (int num = 0; num <= 100; num++)
                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(num);
                    }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

edit:word

Comment: Use a counter and increment it whenever it's an even number. Stop the loop when the counter reaches the number you get from your input.

Comment: Thank you for your help
. Is there a place where there is not trolls that down vote? A very simple coding question from someone inexperienced Sometimes things need to be explained differently to be understood I'm learning what I can from googleing about C# So I figured this place had active people I could ask

Comment: StackOverflow is a good place but there're rules to follow. I didn't downvote you, but maybe people did it because what you asked is too basic. I suggest you read some basic C# books. Some books about basic programming might be good too. You'll learn how to solve problems with programming,

Comment: Read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you might get better responses next time.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of C# devs are moving towards a functional (LINQ) style

```
using System.Linq;

int top = ... some value    
var first10Evens = Enumerable
   .Range(0, top)
   .Where(n => n % 2 == 0)
   .Take(10);

foreach (var n in first10Evens)
   Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to generate a sequence of even numbers. First ones are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc. See the pattern? Add 2 to get the next number. Or multiply the counter by 2.

```
First  = 2 (1 * 2)
Second = 4 (2 * 2)
Third  = 6 (3 * 2)
Fourth = 8 (4 * 2)
etc
```

The `int.TryParse` will try to parse the input from console. If it's a valid integer, counter is replaced by that number. If it's not, it's 0. Then do a loop while the counter is lower than the input. Multiply the counter by 2 to get the even number.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // get input
        var input = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);

        // print first nth even numbers
        var counter = 0;
        while (counter < input)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine(counter * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo. Add Console.ReadLine() at the end to pause the execution so you can view the result in Visual Studio.
https://ideone.com/pmHDUk

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation Han. now I understand For loops a lot more. Will the counter carry on to loops of foreach and do and while loops? this is the first time I am learning about counter

Comment: Counter is only a variable I use to count how many even numbers the code gets. Learn the scope of variables so you understand where it's accessible and where it's not accessible. Please upvote and accept any answers you deem helpful to you.